# AES+ Base64 Decrypt file appeared garbled

Tags: java, sockets, base64, aes

I am using socket to transfer file and AES 256 to encrypt/decrypt, I use the byte array to accept file's content and encrypt it, but only the first byte size array success to decrypt and other appeared garbled(the encrypted byte size extend to 1368 and AES block size is 128bits not sure is it effect),below is my code:

```
  public void sendfile() {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
            int bytesCount = 0;
            while ((bytesCount = fis.read(byteArray)) >= 0) {
                String encryptString = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
                bos.write(EncryptAES.encrypt(encryptString, "12345").getBytes("UTF-8"));                    
            }
      }
   public void receiveFile(File file, BufferedInputStream bis) {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
        int bytesCount = 0;
        while ((bytesCount = bis.read(byteArray)) >= 0) {
                String encryptString = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
                bos.write(EncryptAES.decrypt(encryptString, "12345").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
}

public static String encrypt(String content,SecretKey secretKey) {       
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] byteContent = cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(byteContent);
}
 public static String decrypt(String content,SecretKey secretKey) {
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] byteCipherText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
        String encryptString = new String(byteCipherText, "UTF-8");
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        encryptString = new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");
        return new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");      
}
```

Comment: It would help to have a *clue* what language you're working in. Please edit and add an appropriate tag. Don't turn this into an un-fun guessing game for people who may be able to help you.

Comment: But as general advice, I'm wondering why you're working with *strings* when the natural domain for encryption/decryption is *bytes* and that seems to be what you're getting from the files too.

Comment: On encryption side you use PKCS5 padding but for decryption you choose NoPadding, change to PKCS5 padding as well. **Security warning** you are using ECB mode that is **unsecure**, you should change to CBC mode or GCM when authentication is needed. Search for Java CBC Cipheroutputstream to get examples for this.

Comment: Why are you working with Bouncy Castle- Java could handle this out of the Box ?

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever already  commented leave out the byteArray to string to byte[] conversions, strings are not suitable for binary data.

Comment: I tried accomplish string and file encryption/decryption in the same function,and it seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for reminding,I will remember to add tag next time, as Michael Fehr said,the error is caused by Padding,I use NoPadding instead of PKCS5,because PKCS5 will cause "pad block corrupted" error. I fixed "pad block corrupted" error by change array size to 768(6144 bits which is common multiple of 128(AES block-size) and 6(Base64 block-size) ) ,it works after using Nopadding for both encryption & decryption(because PKCS5 Padding encyption size is 1048(which cause pad block corrupted)).